# setting max value on numeric value overflow (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I use MYSQL.
When inserting rows to my table, I sometimes have numeric overflow on a signed int column:

```
Data truncation: Out of range value for column XXX at row YYY
```

I want the db to handle it quietly, assigning max value for this column in the overflowed rows.

Do I have a way to do it elegantly?

Comment: Perhaps using trigger `before insert`

Comment: I think you need to share the metadata and sample query

Comment: Thats actually the default behaviour https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/02/07/beware-of-mysql-data-truncation/